# Scalable CakePHP login system

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

We've decided to use CakePHP for a login system and frontend database UI because of all the automagic when adhering to its strict conventions, I know Codeigniter and with CI you can extend the system controller in `system/core/Controller.php` to handle authentication

```
class AdminController extends CI_Controller {

    protected $user;

    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('AdminModel');

        $this->user = $this->AdminModel->user()->row();
        $data->user = $this->user;
        $this->load->vars($data);
    }
}
```

Then by extending it as an application controller, `$user` becomes available globally and the AdminController already extends CI_Controller.

```
class Admin extends AdminController {

    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();

    }

    function index(){

        //$user is global since it's extending AdminController

        $this->data['user'] = $user->someItem;

        //load view etc..

    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct approach with CakePHP, is there a general consensus/best practice for scallable login systems that impliment automagic?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you considered [Symfony](http://symfony.org)? In particular, I'm thinking about [Sonata](http://sonata-project.org/about) and [Packagist via `composer`](https://packagist.org/search/?search_query%5Bquery%5D=symfony) is pretty nifty. Not that CakePHP isn't nifty too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `AuthComponent::user()` where ever you need the details, or `AuthComponent::user('id')` where you need a specific field.

Comment: Thanks, can I define AuthComponent::user() from an extended controller of AppController? I'd like to extend MyController instead of AppController in specific areas of the application.

Comment: You should check the docs for [auth](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html) as it is very easy to extend.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this. For example this will work:

```
 class AppController extends Controller
     class CustomAppController extends AppController
         class BikesController extends CustomAppController
```

Actually that is the implementation of plugins, you should take a look here:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html

The same things happens in plugins, every plugin has a custom PluginNameAppController of which all plugin controllers will extend.

It might be interesting to take a look on plugins anyway because of the clear separation of features in your project.